# How can import a global variable into another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use a global accessToken variable within another file but I keep getting the error `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Taat\Documents\Backend\server\controllers\authController' imported from C:\Users\Taat\Documents\Backend\server\controllers\dataController.js code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`

where I am exporting it within authController and importing it within dataController as you can see below in the code:

authController.js:

```
export let accecssToken;

// rest of my code
```

dataController.js:

```
import { accecssToken } from "./authController";
export async function getActivityId(req, res) {
  const data = await getDataPromise();
  const activityIds = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    activityIds[data[i].id] = []; 
  }
  return res.json(activityIds);
}

export async function getDataPromise() {
  const link = `api/?access_token=${accecssToken}`;
  console.log("Link = ", link);
  const response = await axios.get(link);

  return response.data;
}
```

I do not see what I am doing wrong here can anyone spot it?
Both files are in the same directory as you can see from the error messages paths

Comment: The error message isn’t wrong; there is no file called `authController`.

Comment: Share the code how you are exporting and importing

Answer (score 0):

Just add extension of exported file

```
import { accecssToken } from "./authController.js";
```

or You can use

```
const { accecssToken } = require('./authController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
const {accessToken} = require("./authController");
```

**Though seeing the naming convention and your code you're utilizing the accessToken, I would not recommend adding SECERTS in js files as it could be compromised.**

Make a .env file at the root folder and add all secrets inside.

.env file should look like -

[image]

To use any .env variable, add

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

and then use -

```
const link = `api/?access_token=${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`
```